# transfer int over network

Tags: c#, c++, network-programming, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am new to network programming so I have a question: is it safe to send an integer (let's assume 16 bit integer because 32 has issue with "endianess") in my case between C++ and C# and how do that?

In my program I cast int to char (I know is is lower than 255) and send it. However, I would like to send 32 int. I tried conduct that with protocol buffers. I used WriteVarint32 in C++ and ProtoReader.ReadUInt32 in C# with no success (exception in C#). I thought it will work after I read [this](http://markmail.org/message/v5oy24eyshdb254h#query%3aDeserializeWithLengthPrefix%20c+++page:1+mid%3afcsyebmstgt5nfz2+state%3aresults).

Would you be so kind and suggest me the right way to send an integer between C++ and C# applications? If you explained me how to do that with protocol buffers (protobuf-net in case of C#), I would be very pleased.

Comment: So why would 16bit no have issues with endianness and 32bit have? 16bits will be different in bigendian/littleendian machines. I suggest that you decide an approach (for example protocol buffers) and try it, and ask about the issues that you get.

Comment: @David varint encoding works around endianness (it is implicit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing with protobuf-net, the WithLengthPrefix methods will do this for you. I'd be more than happy to help with this (I'm the author). Btw, the reason it is throwing an exception is that a varint value *by itself* is not normally valid in a protobuf stream. The system will override this in the case of WithLengthPrefix if you pass 0 as the field number (or pass a positive field-number for a more pure protobuf stream; this is optional, though).

As it happens there is a method on ProtoReader to read an isolated varint (without worrying about protobuf stream semantics) it would be trivial for me to add such to ProtoWriter if that would be useful.

Btw - in terms of PrefixStyle, Base128 is the same as varint. Some folks prefer 32-bit prefixes, to marry up with other systems - hence a few others are provided.

Comment: I want to use WithLengthPrefix. My problem is I don't know how should I use C++ Protobuf API to construct the prefix C# protobuf-net can understand. 'Base128 is the same as varint' - I tried to send varint with size. C# aroused System.IO.EndOfStreamException. The prefix is an idea present only in protobuf-net. C++ implementation considers nothing even similiar to that concept.

Comment: @lord - indeed. There is only a brief mention of strategies for this (in the docs), which basically say "add your own length". Re the EOF - I re-deployed the dlls following on from a v2 sample I added in an earlier discussion on this (with you, I believe) - check you have the current release. Can you give a brief few words as to your strategy, i.e. "my message via C++ is 27 bytes, so I've written [TODO: the bytes] as a prefix, then the 27 bytes" - then I should be able to see what you have.

Comment: message Test {
required int32 id = 1;
}
That is the message I want to send. Now I set the id (in C++):  
Test test; test.set_id(1234);
 I send Varint32
coded_output->WriteVarint32(test.ByteSize());
C# application should receive exactly these bytes (in hex) 03 08 d2 09. 03 is the size the rest is the message. Currently, I struggle with sending the response back from C# to C++. I believe I will finish that soon.

Comment: @lord - as it happens, individual primitives (`int` etc) are treated by protobuf-net as a field on a message at field 1, so *the minumum* to get that is `int i = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<int>(source, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0)` or `Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(ms, 1234, PrefixStyle.Base128, 0);` (needs the r404 dll though, due to a bug in the earlier beta). You can of course have a full object with an int property etc - that would work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's going to depend on the network libraries that you use and how compatible they are at either end.  At the lowest level the data is being transferred as stream or block of bytes.  When these bytes are converted back to any more complex structure above a byte (even an int) then the encoding obviously matters and needs to match at both ends.

Easiest thing is just to try it out and see.

It sounds like you might be interested in packing the data as tightly as possible (from your comment on converting ints to chars) in which case maybe you should just write a set of low level packing routines at either end.  That way you have no worries over encoding and you can squeeze every last bit out of the packet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no endianess issues with the varint encoding, it's always little endian by design. It stores the value seven bits at a time starting with the least significant seven bits, and uses the eighth bit as stop bit when there is no more one bits left.

You use the `Read7BitEncodedInt` method in C# to read a varint encoded integer.

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems Read7BitEncodedInt is not available in MonoDevelop I use. Any other idea?

Comment: @lord-didger: It's in the `BinaryReader` class. If you are using some other way to read the data, you can easily adapt the code for it, it's just a few lines of code. You can find the source code here: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid4083672E4B426989ECED8C0C517B0327B94BC1CB.aspx